# Magsafe charger behaving strange

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, magsafe

I have a Macbook Pro 15 late 2011. 
The charger has started to act funky the last few days.

What happens is that I connect it. Light shows as green on the connector and then switches to orange if it needs to be charged.

Then after a few hours the computer just dies while the light on the charger is green. Clicking the battery check on the side shows full battery. But removing the charger and clicking again shows a totally empty battery.

At this point, reconnecting the charger doesn't show any light at all. I have to wait a few minutes connect/disconnect cables a couple of times. Then it starts charging. Then starting the computer again it keeps charging. Then suddenly at a random battery percentage number the light switches to green and just stops charging.

Disconnecting and reconnecting charger doesn't help and no light is shown again. Restarting here seems to help. But it keeps happening.

Resting SMC and/or PRAM doesn't help. The charger, the white square doesn't get hot.

Any ideas?

Battery info:
Battery Information:

Model Information:
  Serial Number:    D8614...
  Manufacturer: SMP
  Device Name:  bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:    0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 406
  Hardware Revision:    2
  Cell Revision:    158
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   5407
  Fully Charged:    No
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   5628
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  913
  Condition:    Normal
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    -2648
  Voltage (mV): 11967

Comment: What is the battery heath in system info?

Comment: @jalynn2 added battery info, looks normal to me.

Comment: IMHO Replace the battery and everything will be fine. To be sure - try different charger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearing the expected cycle count for a battery. According to Apple, your model of MacBook Pro is expected to last for 1000 cycles. You could try swapping the MagSafe charger, but I suspect that the battery is ready to be replaced.

[Apple Support - Determining battery cycle count](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585)

Comment: Tried swapping the charger, that was it. But next time it might be the battery. Thanks!